# How to make a pivot table linking two user ID's?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Say, I have this Laravel 5.3 setup

Users Table

```
id | name | password
```

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }
}
```

Profile Table

```
id | user_id
```

Profile Model

```
class Profile extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

now I want people to be able to follow each other's profiles. I need to make a pivot table that makes a relationship between two `user_id`'s, or link users with profiles or something (but they already are linked to their own profile?), but I don't know how. I'm kinda lost. Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Why not have a `user_follows` table with the following structure:

id | user_id | follows_id

Then you can have the following to get the users the user follows and the users following the user, respectively:

```
public function follows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_follows', 'user_id', 'follows_id');
}


public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_follows', 'follows_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Check out how many-to-many relationships work here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many